# Chrome Frame: Access is denied error in IE9

Tags: google-chrome-frame

I am attempting to use Chrome-Frame on a site I'm building. 
In IE8 and below, everything works fine...
In IE9 I get this error:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
cf-dlpage.js, line78 character 209
```

No idea what to do!

here is the conditional that is triggering the behaviour:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
  <style>
        body {
            overflow-y:hidden;
        }
      .chromeFrameOverlayContent {
            border:none;
            overflow:hidden;            
        }
      .chromeFrameOverlayContent iframe {
            border:none;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
      .chromeFrameOverlayCloseBar {
            display:none;
        }
      .chromeFrameOverlayUnderlay {
            background-image:url(/img/bg.png);
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
        }

  </style> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        CFInstall.check({
            url: "/fix/update.html",
            mode: "overlay",
            destination: "/"
        });
    };
  </script> 
  <![endif]-->
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related ticket here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103925) it sounds that its related to your problem. i hope it helps.
read comment from erikwright@chromium.org, is the last comment right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this:

1. Your page is on `www.example.com`
2. The installation routine creates an `iframe` with a url `www.google.com/...`
3. The `iframe` page itself executes Javascript and tries to read `window.parent`, but...
4. ... this is not allowed because both frames have different domains.

The only solutions seem to be:

1. Create your own install script
2. Google fixes their script

I wasted a whole day trying to work around this problem (nested frames, custom scripts, routing Google requests through my server,...) until it dawned me *why* Google seems to ignore this bug:

**Most people simply don't notice the problem**. The installation is performed successfully, regardless of this error. To actually get a message box you have to enable Javascript debugging or the Show Javascript errors feature.

You and I have enabled said features because we are developers, so naturally we freak out, but Average Joe won't notice anything.